# QT QCharts add and remove series

Tags: c++, qt

How i should add and remove series from qchart?

The main mess is that QChart some how store QAxis and QSeries, QSeries themselves refer to QAxis.Above that all that objects are heavy connected.

So instead of pseudo code like this:

```
 void someclass::set_series(QLineSeries*someQLineSeries){
 somechart->removeAllSeries();
 somechart->removeAllAxis();
 somechart->addSeries(someQLineSeries);
 }
```

I should use that:
(zlineseries additionaly store 2 pointers to its axis)

```
void zhplotview::attach_dt_series(ZLineSeries *series)
if(chart)
{

    qDebug()<<"NOT DELETED CHART";
    if(viewer)
    {
        qDebug()<<"NOT DELETED VIEWER";
        qDebug()<<"Okay. Try to clear old links and create chart again";

        //let chart have 1 series
        auto slist=chart->series();
        ZLineSeries *old_series=dynamic_cast<ZLineSeries*>(slist.at(0));

        old_series->detachAxis(old_series->axis_x);
        old_series->detachAxis(old_series->axis_y);

        chart->removeAxis(old_series->axis_x);
        chart->removeAxis(old_series->axis_y);
        vbl->removeWidget(viewer);

        chart->removeSeries(old_series);

        disconnect(viewer);
        disconnect(chart);

        delete chart;
        delete viewer;

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"chart is 0, but viewer not";
        return;
    }
}

chart=new QChart();
chart->addSeries(series);
chart->addAxis(series->axis_x,Qt::AlignBottom);
chart->addAxis(series->axis_y,Qt::AlignLeft);
series->attachAxis(series->axis_x);
series->attachAxis(series->axis_y);

viewer=new QZChartView(chart,this);
vbl->addWidget(viewer);
```

Comment: The design of QtChart classes is cleary for build-once and display only.  If you need to update often, it is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's three years later, but I use a little workaround for this, maybe it's interesting for someone.

On every delta I generate a new chart, and just replace the old one. In order to be fast enough, I keep some data pre-calculated in stack.

Comment: please add an example of your code to better explain your solution